# Selenium Error when using Crontab @reboot for python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, raspberry-pi, cron

I have a Raspberry Pi that I would like to start a couple of python scripts at the time of reboot with `crontab`.  I have successfully run each of the scripts manually by calling `python name_of_script.py` from the terminal, yet when I run via crontab, I am presented with the following traceback.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/photo_frames/becky/get_urls.py", line 11, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 150, in __init__
    keep_alive=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 92, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 179, in start_session response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, capabilities)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: connection refused
```

Any pointers on diagnosis would be greatly appreciated, unfortunately my Google-fu has let me down in regards to this error.

Answer (score 0):

For Redhat/CentOS/Fedora, install **Xvfb** and **pyvirtualdisplay**

```
sudo yum install Xvfb
pip install pyvirtualdisplay
```

Test **Xvfb** and **pyvirtualdisplay** that gives no exceptions

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
display = Display(visible=0, size=(1024,768))
display.start()
display.stop()
```

Enclose to your Selenium code

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
display = Display(visible=0, size=(1024,768))
display.start()

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
driver.quit()

display.stop()
```